# Вызов python скрипта в node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

Имеется два скрипта на Node.js и на python. Пытаюсь, чтобы python-скрипт вызывался у меня в js-скрипте и присылал мне json, но моя функция в js возвращает пустой массив. Что надо исправить?

И второе, как в js-скрипте мне сделать так, чтобы он засыпал допустим на 3 секунды (т.е. нужен аналог `time.sleep(3)` в python).

Скрипт на nodejs:

```
function draw() {
    const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ["./generationData.py"]);
    let lst = [];
    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
        var myStr = data.toString();
        var obj = JSON.parse(myStr);
        lst.push(obj); 
    });
    return lst;
};

console.log(draw());
```

Скрипт на python:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import math
import json

def get_data(step):
    id_val = 'prop.fuel'
    x = int(str(datetime.now().timestamp()).replace('.', ''))
    y = math.sin(step*math.pi/180)

    data =  {
        'timestamp': x, 
        'value': y, 
        'id': id_val
    }

    return json.dumps(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_data(5))
```

Comment: В питоне пропущен один импорт: `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: @CrazyElf это плохо перекопировал код. Но он у меня есть. Извиняюсь за опечатку

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Причина такого поведения в том, что `lst` возвращается после объявления обработчиков событий, а не после того как эти обработчики были вызваны.

Есть 2 эффективных способа решить задачу: Promise и callback.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

(async () => {
  try {
    const lst = await drawAsync();
    console.log('async:', lst);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('async error:', err);
  }
})();

drawCallback(([err, lst]) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('cb error:', err);
  }
  console.log('cb:', lst);
});

async function drawAsync() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python3', ["./generationData.py"]);

    let lst = [];
    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
      var myStr = data.toString();
      var obj = JSON.parse(myStr);
      lst.push(obj);
    });

    pythonProcess.on('close', (code) => resolve(lst));

    pythonProcess.on('error', (err) => reject(err));

  });
}

function drawCallback(cb) {
  const pythonProcess = spawn('python3', ["./generationData.py"]);

  let lst = [];
  pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
    var myStr = data.toString();
    var obj = JSON.parse(myStr);
    lst.push(obj);
  });

  pythonProcess.on('close', (code) => cb([null, lst]));

  pythonProcess.on('error', (err) => cb([err, lst]));
}
```

[Почитать про Promise.](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)

[Почитать про callback.](https://learn.javascript.ru/callbacks)

---

UPD на запрос про цикл и sleep:

```
(async () => {
  let count = 100;
  while (count--) {
    console.log('async:', await drawAsync());
    await delay(500);
  }
})();

async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

---

UPD2 на запрос про бесконечный вызов на callback-ах:

```
let f;
(f = () => {
  drawCallback(([err, lst]) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('cb error:', err);
    }
    console.log('cb:', lst);
    setTimeout(f, 1000);
  });
})();
```

Comment: А если. сделаю такой цикл, то почему скрипт у меня перестает что то выводить?
`while (true){
    (async () => {
        try {
        const lst = await drawAsync();
        console.log(lst[0]);
        } 
        catch (err) {
            console.error('async error:', err);
        }
    })();
}`

Comment: во-первых - причитай про промисы. во-вторых - это другой вопрос, а на SO вопросы принято разделять. в-третьих - что ты хочешь получить в результате - бесконечный вызов своего скрипта?

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь) мне очень помог ваш ответ!
Приму Ваши замечания. Спасибо большое!
А на третье, то да, если не сложно, то как вызывать бесконечно мой скрипт питоновский? Или для этого нужен отдельный таск?

Comment: пожалуйста :). бесконечный (ну, ограниченный каунтером) вызов я дописал в конец ответа. «отдельный таск» или как-то ещё - зависит от целей приложения и, как следствие, его архитектуры

Comment: Простите, что еще раз отвлекаю, но как такой же цикл со sleep написать для drawCallback? Просто у меня получается совсем иначе. Он у меня ждет 1 секунду и высылает мне все сразу 100 одинаковых значений

Comment: дополнил ответ, но имей ввиду, что программировать промисы гораздо удобнее, чем коллбеки

Comment: спасибо! попробую разобраться в этом) Вы мне очень помогли!