# NodeJS вопрос по работе с модулем FS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, async-await

Работаю над небольшим проектом, где стоит задача считать json файлы в папке , на их основе собрать строку и вернуть ее. Казалось бы - просто, но я завис на моменте асинхронности, уже как только не пробовал и менял на Sync методы Ноды, и async/await, но у меня не получается вернуть контент. Функция возвращает значение до того, как все файлы прочитаются и сформируется результирующая строка.

Это текущий вид файлов:

```
 function loadReport(user) {
    const data =  fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../reports', user))
    return JSON.parse(data).content
}
//Generate full report using reports files
const  fullyReportGenerator = async function(){
     var fullReport = ''
     var finalRep = await fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, '../reports'), (err , files)=>{

            files.forEach((user) =>  {
                    fullReport += loadReport(user)
            })
           return fullReport // Вот тут в переменной все то, что надо
    })

    return finalRep; // А вот тут уже undefined
}
```

Вызываю потом эту функцию в другом файле:

```
bot.command('/report', (ctx) => {
    fullyReportGenerator()
})
```

Я понимаю, что ответ на поверхности, но я уже немного запутался и прошу совета.

Comment: у тебя тут такой зоопарк... прочитай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290 (и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1178589/2659). пингани меня через собачку, если не поможет, я поясню на твоём коде

Comment: `fs.readdir()` не возвращает промис, поэтому `await` тут бесполезен. Как вариант, используйте [`fs-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) вместо `fs`.

Comment: @Yaant не возвращает, это - верно, но fs-extra тут лишняя так как есть https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options

Comment: @Yaant , да, тут я уже просто сам себя запутал  и не могу распутаться. 
Я вообще вычитал, что если подключить как const fs = require('fs').promises;, то все функции будут возвращать промис.

Comment: @nörbörnën, а, да, тут я отстал от жизни. Забыл, что в `fs` добавили нативную поддержку промисов. Просто у нас тут проект базируется на 8 ноде, а там такого не было. :)

Comment: @nörbörnën похоже, мне все таки нужна помощь. Я все с нуля переписал, но мне кажется "зоопарк" только больше стал. Меня пугает то, что у меня внутри одного промиса  - другой и я теряюсь, как это правильно организовать.

Comment: @Yaant эх, я тебя понимаю

Comment: так какую функцию ты в итоге вызываешь? с promise или без?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Асинхронно на async/await

```
const { promises: fs } = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const bot = {
  command: (cmd, cb) => cb({ctx: 'ctx'})
};

bot.command('/report', (ctx) => {
  fullyReportGenerator()
    .then((reportRawData) => {
      console.log(reportRawData);
      console.log(ctx);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});

async function fullyReportGenerator() {
  const reportDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../reports');
  const reportFiles = await readDir(reportDirectoryPath);

  const reportData = [];
  for (const filePath of reportFiles) {
    const reportRawDataItem = await readFile(filePath);

    if (typeof reportRawDataItem === 'object' && 'content' in reportRawDataItem) {
      reportData.push(reportRawDataItem.content);
    }
  }
  
  return reportData;
}

async function readDir(dirPath) {
  const files = await fs.readdir(dirPath);
  return files.map((x) => path.join(dirPath, x));
}

async function readFile(filePath) {
  const data = await fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'});
  try {
    const json = JSON.parse(data);
    return json;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Приведённый код является не более чем иллюстрацией подхода к решению задачи или решением для небольшого количества небольших отчётов.

Не учитывает, что в каталоге `report` могут быть подкаталоги (решается [проверками](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_stat_path_options) и рекурсивным вызовом readDir).

Чтение файлов происходит последовательно, но при большом количестве файлов нужно распараллелить (я использую [p-queue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue)).

Не оптимально с тз производительности, если файлы отчётов большого размера, но можно уйти на [стримы](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options).

#### Полностью синхронный

На небольших количествах файлов и небольших данных будет, скорее всего, работать быстрее.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const bot = {
  command: (cmd, cb) => cb({ctx: 'ctx'})
};

bot.command('/report', (ctx) => {
  const reportRawData = fullyReportGenerator();
  console.log(reportRawData);
  console.log(ctx);
});

function fullyReportGenerator() {
  const reportDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../reports');
  const reportFiles = readDir(reportDirectoryPath);

  const reportData = [];
  for (const filePath of reportFiles) {
    const reportRawDataItem = readFile(filePath);

    if (typeof reportRawDataItem === 'object' && 'content' in reportRawDataItem) {
      reportData.push(reportRawDataItem.content);
    }
  }
  
  return reportData;
}

function readDir(dirPath) {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
  return files.map((x) => path.join(dirPath, x));
}

function readFile(filePath) {
  const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'});
  try {
    const json = JSON.parse(data);
    return json;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: выдумывать решение на callback-ах мне совершенно лениво, сорян