# Python как отправлять данные клиенту

Tags: python, node.js, websocket

У меня есть серверная и клиентская часть на Node.js. Все работает в реал-тайме. Но мне бы хотелось написать python-скрипт для отправки json данных к клиенту при условии, что запущен сервере на Node.js. У меня уже получилось вызывать python-скрипт в js, но мне бы хотелось непосредственно сразу отправлять данные к клиенту.

У меня мысль сделать это через Веб-сокеты. Но не понимаю как, дайте совета в каком направлении двигаться или примеры пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [твоём случае](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1178545/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-python-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-node-js) лучше оставить "серверную часть на Node.js" отвечать за сетевое взаимодействие с клиентов, а "python-скрипт" обрабатывать данные. Ещё одно, в рамках python-скрипта, сетевое взаимодействие с клиентом только усложнит систему.

Организуй очередь выполнения задач (nodejs Worker threads, Bull, Bee, Agenda) в "серверной части на Node.js" websocket-соединение - клиент не обязан ждать результат расчёта. Пусти вычисления в асинхронном режиме и отсылай клиенту по мере готовности.

Comment: Вы как всегда хороши) спасибо за совет! Буда разбираться в том, что написали))
Но до асинхронности мне еще далеко. Ведь я только начал изучать js. 
Асинхронность, это использование async/await?

Comment: смогли бы подсказать, как именно усложнится система при использовании сетевого взаимодействия python?