# Получение результата выполнения кода на другом языке в Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

я хочу сделать функцию которая будет присылать результат выполнения кода на другом яп в среде node js,можно ли это как-то сделать с помощью онлайн сервисов(тогда каких),докера,модулей или что-то подобного?

Comment: ты хочешь [локально запустить скрипт на другом языке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178545/2659) или что-то другое?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы я ввёл условно 
`function a (lp,code) {//code } console.log(a('cpp','cout << "Print a String" << endl; ') //return Print a String`

Comment: пишешь код во временный файл, пишешь словарь интерпретаторов языка (имя языка: пускач), запускаешь spawn-ом или чем-то из child_process. думаешь как бы первая запущенная чужая программа не снесла тебе корневой раздел. или копаешь в сторону сервисов типа https://ideone.com/

Comment: Ок,спасибо вам огромное