# Показать в режиме реального времени логи во время выполнения скрипта WebApplication на NodeJS/express

Tags: node.js, express

всем добрый день!
я хотела бы написать приложение на nodejs + express, которое запускает определенный скрипт при клике на кнопку;
результаты выполнения этого скрипта я бы хотела выводить в браузер в режиме реального времени.
есть ли доступный способ показывать подобные логи в веб приложении?
есть ли мб доступные пакеты в nodejs, которые я не смогла нагуглить?
PS:
веб страницу верстаю на ejs и нашла подобный код, но который не позволяет показать значения из консоли в окне браузера. я нашла только этот код в некоторых статьях:

```
<% console.log('test') %>
```

но такой код, к сожалению, выводит test в консоль раннера при старте приложения. это не то, что мне нужно

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно смотреть в сторону https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У нас есть две подзадачи:

- запускать скрипт при клике на кнопку
- результаты выполнения этого скрипта в браузер в режиме реального времени

---

> ### child_process.spawn(command[, args][, options])
>
> command  The command to run.
>
> args <string[]> List of string arguments.
>
> options
>
> The child_process.spawn() method spawns a new process using the given
> command, with command-line arguments in args. If omitted, args
> defaults to an empty array.

Для запуска команды на стороне сервера будем использовать [spawn](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), а в качестве запускаемых скриптов будем использовать команды *nix-овой консоли. Но, конечно же, можно запускать всё, что может запуститься, например, [скрипт на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1178589/2659).

---

> ### WebSocket
>
> Протокол WebSocket («веб-сокет»), описанный в спецификации RFC 6455,
> обеспечивает возможность обмена данными между браузером и сервером
> через постоянное соединение. Данные передаются по нему в обоих
> направлениях в виде «пакетов», без разрыва соединения и дополнительных
> HTTP-запросов.
>
> WebSocket особенно хорош для сервисов, которые нуждаются в постоянном
> обмене данными, например онлайн игры, торговые площадки, работающие в
> реальном времени, и т.д.

Передавать данные в режиме реального времени будем [протоколом WebSocket](https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket).

Сервер сделаем библиотекой [ws: a Node.js WebSocket library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws).

Клиентскую часть на браузерном [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

Ну и для общения клиента с сервером выдумаем протокол. Клиент сообщает серверу какую команду он хочет выполнить и набор аргументов запуска команды в формате

```
{ cmd: string; payload: Record<string, any>; }
```

---

#### Серверная часть

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (_request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
const webSocketServer = new WebSocket.Server({
  server
});

const dispatchEvent = (
  /** @type {WebSocket.Data} */ message,
  /** @type {WebSocket} */ ws
) => {
  /** @type {{ cmd: string; payload: Record<string, any>; }} */
  const { cmd, payload } = JSON.parse(message);
  if (cmd) {
    let args = [];
    switch (cmd) {
      case 'find':
        args = ['.', '-name', payload.name];
        break;
      case 'tail':
        args = ['-f', payload.name];
        break;
      default:
    }
    const workerProcess = spawn(cmd, args);
    workerProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => ws.send(data.toString('utf-8')));
    workerProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => ws.send(data.toString('utf-8')));
  }
};

webSocketServer.on('connection', (ws) => {
  ws.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    ws.send(e);
  });
  ws.on('message', (m) => dispatchEvent(m, ws));
});

const port = +(process.env.PORT || 3000);
server.listen(
  port,
  () => console.log('Server started'),
);
```

#### Клиентская часть

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script>
      const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
      ws.onerror = (err) => console.log(err);
      ws.onclose = () => console.log('ws::close');
      ws.onmessage = (msg) => {
        document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += msg.data;
      }

      function handleForm(ev, f) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = '';

        const { cmd, ...payload } = Array.from(new FormData(f)).reduce(
          (acc, [key, value]) => {
            if (value !== null && value !== undefined && value !== '') {
              acc[key] = value;
            }
            return acc;
          },
          {}
        );

        ws.send(
          JSON.stringify({ cmd, payload })
        );
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      pre {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        padding: 1em;
        font-size: 8pt;
        width: 80%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="cmd" onsubmit="handleForm(event, this)">
      <select name="cmd">
        <option value="find">find</option>
        <option value="cal">calendar</option>
        <option value="tail">tail</option>
      </select>
      <input name="name" />
      <button>send</button>
    </form>
    <pre id="console"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Результат запуска

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]