# Linux nodejs командная строка

Tags: javascript, node.js

Например у меня открыто окно командной строки.  Можно ли написать на node js программу, в которой бы я указывал  pid открытого окна, и дальше из nodejs например я бы передал,любые команды существующие в командной строке,в это открытое окно. Возможно ли такое делать на node?

Comment: Почемуж бред? Предположим у тебя есть вэб морда, на ней отображены команды в html, ты тыкаешь на эту команду, она передается через json на сервер с node, то есть node разобрав json запрос, определяет что команда например ls, и должен ее исполнить в командной строке.

Comment: может я неправильно понял изначально, но с уточнением похоже на банальный ajax/xhr запрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1227167/2659

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1327884/2659

Comment: возможно натолкнёт на мысли

Comment: nörbörnën Спасибо, что то похоже на то что я хотел узнать, надо разбираться,как ты эту тему гуглил друг? я чет вообще не могу понять как это спрашивать))

Comment: я это никак не гуглил, я это из головы написал